# Android NDK Error : No function renaming possible

Tags: c++, android-ndk

I've manage to make my Android Project work with a Visual Studio project. The only problem I have is when I compiled the c++ project the vsc++ compiler gives me this error:

`android-ndk-r6b\platforms\android-9\arch-x86\usr\include\sys\cdefs.h(252): fatal error C1189: #error :  "No function renaming possible"`

If anyone had this problem before, any input would be nice.

The error happens when I include the .h that contains includes to those files

- jni.h
- android\log.h

EDIT :

I've looked at cdefs.h around line 252 :

```
245 | #if !defined(_STANDALONE) && !defined(_KERNEL)
246 | #ifdef __GNUC__
247 | #define   __RENAME(x) ___RENAME(x)
248 | #else
249 | #ifdef __lint__
250 | #define   __RENAME(x) __symbolrename(x)
251 | #else
252 | #error "No function renaming possible"
253 | #endif /* __lint__ */
254 | #endif /* __GNUC__ */
255 | #else /* _STANDALONE || _KERNEL */
256 | #define   __RENAME(x) no renaming in kernel or standalone environment
257 | #endif
```

But honestly, I'm not sure what no renaming... means.

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem? I'm having the same isues right now.

Comment: Unfortunatly I never did found a solution, but the project took a different direction so we didn't need the NDK anymore. But from what I could tell at the time the error came from compatibilty issues between the ndk library and some c++ library (maybe OO c++ code that is not supported or something...)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `cdefs.h` from `$(NDKROOT)/.../includes` somehow conflicts with the "default" `cdefs.h` from Visual Studio. Try to directly address the folder `android` in your includes and change `#include <android/log.h>` to `#include <log.h>` in your source file.

Regarding the `jni.h` I have no further clue...

Answer (score 0):

There is `#error` pragma in the source code. Find this pragma and explore it's vicinity to check for any comments and / or `#ifdef` that might give you a hint on what's the problem.

Comment: You mean I should put a #pragma call in my .h ?

Comment: No-no-no, find the `#error` the compiler is barking at, you'll probably see comments that will explain the problem. More presicely - look around the line 252 of `android-ndk-r6b\platforms\android-9\arch-x86\usr\include\sys\cdefs.h`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same thing, compile my Android code using Visual Studio.  Even though Studio has no tablet emulator, I could at least run some of my logic under Studio, the parts that do not involve anything specific to Android (e.g. UI drawing).  Why bother with such a limited dev environment?  Well, simply because Studio has a very nice C++ editor and it compiles much more quickly then Android Studio/Gradle.  And I have a lot of non-UI logic that I need to get right.  So I'm dividing my work into a pre-step, which I think can be done more quickly with Studio.

For me, I copied over jni.h (from android NDK's x86 folder).  And I made some tweaks...

```
#define __NDK_FPABI__
//#include <sys/cdefs.h>
...
#define JNIEXPORT  //gdh: __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
```

That made Studio happy.